# Why do my link not work after adding negative margin to nav?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was make a Jquery function to make the navigation bar stick to the top of the page when scrolled past the header.

To make it look smooth I had to add `padding-top:110px` to the content div and `margin-bottom: -80px` to the nav div. Now my links do not work.

Any guesses to why? And how can I fix this to get everything in order?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var stickyNavTop = $('.nav').offset();

  var stickyNav = function() {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop.top) {
      $('.nav').addClass('sticky');
    } else {
      $('.nav').removeClass('sticky');
    }
  };

  stickyNav();

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    stickyNav();
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#body {
  width: 80%;
  min-height: 100%;
  border: 1pxcenter;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  margin: auto;
}
.nav {
  margin-bottom: -80px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
}
a:visited {
  color: black;
}
a:hover {
  color: yellow;
}
a:active {
  color: green;
}
#link {
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  border: 1px dotted green;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: none;
}
.sticky {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: fixed;
  width: 80%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  border-top: 0;
}
.nav div p {
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-size: 1em;
}
#content {
  border: 1px solid green;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 110px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin: none;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="header">
  <h1>FrontYard Fairways</h1>
  <h2>"Fairways at a fair price"</h2>
</header>
<nav class="nav">
  <a href="FYFHome.html">
    <div id="link">
      <p>Home</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="Services.html">
    <div id="link">
      <p>Services</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="Customers.html">
    <div id="link">
      <p>Our Customers</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="About.html">
    <div id="link">
      <p>About</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="Contact.html">
    <div id="link">
      <p>Contact</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</nav>
<main id="content">
  <div>
    <p>
      Blahblahablahahlahablhablahablhaab lahablhablahablahabla hablahBlahblahablaha hlahablhablahablhaablahablhablahablahablahablahBlahb lahablahahlahablhablahablhaablahablhablahablahablahablahBlahblahablahahlahablhablahabl haablahablhab lahablahablahablahBlahblahablahahlahablhablahab
      lhaablahablhablahabl ahablahablahBlahblahabl ahahlaha hablahablhaablahablhablahabla blahablahablah Blahblahablahahlahablhabl ahablhaablahablhablahablahablahablahBlahblahablahahlahablhablahablhaab lahablhablahablahablah ablahBlahbl hablahahlahablhablahablhaablahablha
      blahablahablahablahBlahblahablahahlahablhablahablhaab lahablhablahab lahablahBl ahblahablahahla hablhablahablh aablahablhablahablahablahablahBlahblahablahah lahablhablahablhaablahablhablahablaha blahablahBlahbla hablahahlahablhablahablhaablahablhablahablahablahablahBla
      hblahablahahlahablhablah ablhaablahablhablahablahablahablahBlahblahab ahahlahablhablahablh aablahablhablahablahablahablahBla hblahablaha hlahablhablahablhaablahablhablahab lahablahablahBlahblahablahahlahablhablahablhaa blahablhablahablahablahablahBlahblahablahahlahablhablahablhaablahablhabl
      ahablahablahablahBlahblahablahahlahablhablahablhaablahablhablaha blahablahablahB lahblahablahahlahablhablahablhaablahablhablahablahablahablahBlahblahablahahlahablhablahablhaablahablhablahablahablah ablahBlahblahablahahlah abl ha lahablh aablahablhablahablahablahablahBlahblaha
      blahahlahablhablahablh aablahablhablahablahablahablahBla hblahablahahlahablhablahablhaablahablhablahablahablahablah Blahblahablahahlahablhablahablhaab lahablhablahablahabla hablahBlahblahablaha hlahablhablahablhaablahablhablahablahablahablahBlahb
      lahablahahlahablhablahablhaablahablhablahablahablahablahBlahblahablahahlahablhablahabl haablahablhab lahablahablahablahBlahblahablahahlahablhablahab lhaablahablhablahabl ahablahablahBlahblahabl ahahlaha hablahablhaablahablhablahabla blahablahablah
      Blahblahablahahlahablhabl ahablhaablahablhablahablahablahablahBlahblahablahahlahablhablahablhaab lahablhablahablahablah ablahBlahbl hablahahlahablhablahablhaablahablha blahablahablahablahBlahblahablahahlahablhablahablhaab lahablhablahab lahablahBl
      ahblahablahahla hablhablahablh aablahablhablahablahablahablahBlahblahablahah lahablhablahablhaablahablhablahablaha blahablahBlahbla hablahahlahablhablahablhaablahablhablahablahablahablahBla hblahablahahlahablhablah ablhaablahablhablahablahablahablahBlahblahab
      ahahlahablhablahablh aablahablhablahablahablahablahBla hblahablaha hlahablhablahablhaablahablhablahab lahablahablahBlahblahablahahlahablhablahablhaa blahablhablahablahablahablahBlahblahablahahlahablhablahablhaablahablhabl ahablahablahablahBlahblahablahahlahablhablahablhaablahablhablaha
      blahablahablahB lahblahablahahlahablhablahablhaablahablhablahablahablahablahBlahblahablahahlahablhablahablhaablahablhablahablahablah ablahBlahblahablahahlah abl ha lahablh aablahablhablahablahablahablahBlahblaha blahahlahablhablahablh aablahablhablahablahablahablahBla
      hblahablahahlahablhablahablhaablahablhablahablahablahablah
    </p>
  </div>

</main>
```

Comment: PS When I take away the margin-bottom: -80px; the links work. When I add it they dont. >.>

Comment: What do you mean by "links are not working"? I do not see any problems

Comment: My links stopped working after I added the margin-bottom:-80px;

Comment: So none to the hover or active affects are not working and the link became unclickable. You say it looks fine but in testing is does not.

Comment: despite some disposition problems, the hover  and active pseudo-classes are well handled and clicking on the links loads the new location. Tested on firefox an chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have overlapping (invisible) elements from your content that covers your links.

The following CSS:

`#content{
    padding-top: 110px;
}`

forces your content to sit on top of your navigation links blocking them from being clicked.

There are several solutions to this.  One way to confirm that this is the case is to remove

`#content{
    padding-top: 110px;
}`

and replace it with

`#content{
    position:relative; 
    top:110px;
}`

A better way to debug the issue is to open Chrome DevTools and inspecting the `#content` div to see where the box model overlaps your links and adjust accordingly.

Comment: thx that worked, the issure was that the links position was not set. I had to change it to relative so that it would continue with the page flow relative with the surrounding elements. bump my question plz! +1

Comment: Thanx @JavaFox. I had negative margins to with Headers and Breadcrumbs. By setting position: relative the links now work :-)

Answer (score 0):

I removed the negative margins applied to the main element, to your nav bar, and removed the height of your header. And also some little other things.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var stickyNavTop = $('.nav').offset();

  var stickyNav = function() {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop.top) {
      $('.nav').addClass('sticky');
    } else {
      $('.nav').removeClass('sticky');
    }
  };

  stickyNav();

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    stickyNav();
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#body {
  width: 80%;
  min-height: 100%;
  border: 1pxcenter;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
  /* height: 40%; => that makes your header overlapping with your nav bar*/ 
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  margin: auto;
}
.nav {
  
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 1;
  /*
  the support of position:sticky is bad: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  */
  background: rgba( 255,255,255,0.9);
  transition: width 0.5s;
}
a:visited {
  color: black;
}
a:hover {
  color: yellow;
}
a:active {
  color: green;
}
#link {
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(20% - 1px );;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  border: 1px dotted green;
  border-right-width: 0;
  
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: none;
}
.sticky {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: fixed;
  width: 80%;
  top: 0;
  border-top: 0;
}
.sticky + #content{
  margin-top:80px
}

.nav div p {
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-size: 1em;
}
#content {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding-top:1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="header">
  <h1>FrontYard Fairways</h1>
  <h2>"Fairways at a fair price"</h2>
</header>
<nav class="nav">
  <a href="FYFHome.html">
    <div id="link">
      <p>Home</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="Services.html">
    <div id="link">
      <p>Services</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="Customers.html">
    <div id="link">
      <p>Our Customers</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="About.html">
    <div id="link">
      <p>About</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="Contact.html">
    <div id="link">
      <p>Contact</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</nav>
<main id="content">
  <div>
    <p>
      Blahblahablahahlahablhablahablhaab <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
lhablahablahabla hablahBlahblahablaha hlahablhablahablhaablahablhablahablahablahablahBlahb lahablahahlahablhablahablhaablahablhablahablahablahablahBlahblahablahahlahablhablahabl haablahablhab lahablahablahablahBlahblahablahahlahablhablahab
      lhaablahablhablahabl ahablahablahBlahblahabl ahahlaha hablahablhaablahablhablahabla blahablahablah Blahblahablahahlahablhabl ahablhaablahablhablahablahablahablahBlahblahablahahlahablhablahablhaab lahablhablahablahablah ablahBlahbl hablahahlahablhablahablhaablahablha
      blahablahablahablahBlahblahablahahlahablhablahablhaab lahablhablahab lahablahBl ahblahablahahla hablhablahablh aablahablhablahablahablahablahBlahblahablahah lahablhablahablhaablahablhablahablaha blahablahBlahbla hablahahlahablhablahablhaablahablhablahablahablahablahBla
      hblahablahahlahablhablah ablhaablahablhablahablahablahablahBlahblahab ahahlahablhablahablh aablahablhablahablahablahablahBla hblahablaha hlahablhablahablhaablahablhablahab lahablahablahBlahblahablahahlahablhablahablhaa blahablhablahablahablahablahBlahblahablahahlahablhablahablhaablahablhabl
      ahablahablahablahBlahblahablahahlahablhablahablhaablahablhablaha blahablahablahB lahblahablahahlahablhablahablhaablahablhablahablahablahablahBlahblahablahahlahablhablahablhaablahablhablahablahablah ablahBlahblahablahahlah abl ha lahablh aablahablhablahablahablahablahBlahblaha
      blahahlahablhablahablh aablahablhablahablahablahablahBla hblahablahahlahablhablahablhaablahablhablahablahablahablah Blahblahablahahlahablhablahablhaab lahablhablahablahabla hablahBlahblahablaha hlahablhablahablhaablahablhablahablahablahablahBlahb
      lahablahahlahablhablahablhaablahablhablahablahablahablahBlahblahablahahlahablhablahabl haablahablhab lahablahablahablahBlahblahablahahlahablhablahab lhaablahablhablahabl ahablahablahBlahblahabl ahahlaha hablahablhaablahablhablahabla blahablahablah
      Blahblahablahahlahablhabl ahablhaablahablhablahablahablahablahBlahblahablahahlahablhablahablhaab lahablhablahablahablah ablahBlahbl hablahahlahablhablahablhaablahablha blahablahablahablahBlahblahablahahlahablhablahablhaab lahablhablahab lahablahBl
      ahblahablahahla hablhablahablh aablahablhablahablahablahablahBlahblahablahah lahablhablahablhaablahablhablahablaha blahablahBlahbla hablahahlahablhablahablhaablahablhablahablahablahablahBla hblahablahahlahablhablah ablhaablahablhablahablahablahablahBlahblahab
      ahahlahablhablahablh aablahablhablahablahablahablahBla hblahablaha hlahablhablahablhaablahablhablahab lahablahablahBlahblahablahahlahablhablahablhaa blahablhablahablahablahablahBlahblahablahahlahablhablahablhaablahablhabl ahablahablahablahBlahblahablahahlahablhablahablhaablahablhablaha
      blahablahablahB lahblahablahahlahablhablahablhaablahablhablahablahablahablahBlahblahablahahlahablhablahablhaablahablhablahablahablah ablahBlahblahablahahlah abl ha lahablh aablahablhablahablahablahablahBlahblaha blahahlahablhablahablh aablahablhablahablahablahablahBla
      hblahablahahlahablhablahablhaablahablhablahablahablahablah
    </p>
  </div>

</main>
```